# How to remove numbers displayed on top of the softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I've tried a lot of InputFilter combinations to no avail.

The numbers I'm referring to are these in the first row:

[image]

I need this for an EditText that will receive a person's name. I already managed to disable the word suggestions with `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`, however this enabled the first row displayed in the image above.

Comment: There are dozens, if not hundreds, of input method editors (soft keyboards) pre-installed on Android devices. There are many more available for users to download and install, from app distribution channels like the Play Store. You, as the app developer, do not have absolute control over them. At best, you provide some hints as to your desired behavior, such as what you are doing with `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`.

Comment: However, there is no requirement for any input method editor to disable word suggestions because you requested `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`. Similarly, there is no specific option to say "please do not show that row of numbers", and even if there were, there is no requirement for any input method editor to honor that request. I cannot rule out the possibility that there is some option that happens to remove those numbers on the one device that you are testing on. Just don't expect any of this to work for all devices and all users.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, can you post this back as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of input method editors (soft keyboards) pre-installed on Android devices. There are many more available for users to download and install, from app distribution channels like the Play Store.

You, as the app developer, do not have absolute control over them. At best, you provide some hints as to your desired behavior, such as what you are doing with `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`.

However:

- There is no requirement for any input method editor to disable word suggestions because you requested `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`
- There is no option to say "please do not show that row of numbers", and even if there were, there is no requirement for any input method editor to honor that request

I cannot rule out the possibility that there is some option that happens to remove those numbers on the one device that you are testing on. Just don't expect any of this to work for all devices and all users.